# How can I import a javascript AMD module into an external TypeScript module?

Tags: javascript, module, typescript, external, amd

How can I import a javascript AMD module into a external TypeScript module?

I'm modularizing my client TypeScript program to use AMD modules managed by bower.
As part of this process, a Typescript module becomes a javascript AMD module, which I then publish.
Now I have a javascript AMD module that I want to include in a TypeScript module, and I don't want to publish the original TypeScript with the javascript AMD.

I cannot figure out how to write my TypeScript code so that it will load a javascript AMD module for which there is no corresponding TypeScript, and it appears that the most recent versions of TypeScript don't support this yet.

If I start with the example from the 0.9.7 TypeScript specification, section 11.2:

File main.ts:

```
import log = require("./log"); 
log.message("hello");
```

File log.ts:

```
export function message(s: string) { 
    console.log(s); 
}
```

I believe I should be able to modify main.ts so that the compiler resolves the "log" reference to the log.js AMD module. 
Below is the log.js file that was produced by running **tsc --module amd main.ts**. It is a correct AMD module.

File log.js:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    function message(s) {
        console.log(s);
    }
    exports.message = message;
});
```

To simulate having a javascript AMD module, compile the above example, and then delete the log.ts file.
If you now try to compile using the same command, it fails with the following errors:

```
./main.ts(1,1): error TS2071: Unable to resolve external module '"./log"'.  
./main.ts(1,1): error TS2072: Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.
```

How can I now modify main.ts so it compiles and resolves against this log.js AMD module?
I can write log.d.ts file if I have to, but would like a method that also works without a declaration file.

If I can learn how to do this in the canonical TypeScript Way, then I can continue the complete modularization of my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I now modify main.ts so I can load and use this log.js AMD module?

If you only the log.js available you can tell typescript about the type information from `log` using `declare` i.e. create a `log.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'log'{
    export function message(s:string);
}
```

And then use it from main.ts as :

```
/// <reference path='log.d.ts'/>    

import log = require('log'); 
log.message("hello");
```

Comment: This worked as you wrote it. But if I keep the name from the original example, "./log", then it fails to compile. I searched through the language spec and found section 12.1.6, Ambient External Module Declarations, that describes the restriction that the module name be a top-level (non-relative) name. However, I can't find an explanation for why this is so. I can only guess that there is no real need for such naming?
Do you you have an explanation for this restriction? Thanks

Comment: Js files should either come from npm or from your RequireJS config. Both of these cases the names are not relative

Comment: I found the requirement for using a string for the name of an AMD module confusing, but found this article describing the usage: https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript