# Re: How can I import a javascript AMD module into an external TypeScript module? (When using module.exports=...)

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, amd

Related question:
[How can I import a javascript AMD module into an external TypeScript module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737337/how-can-i-import-a-javascript-amd-module-into-an-external-typescript-module)

I have tried the workaround in the question above, it surely works. But it did not work when the AMD module returns function itself as the module (not `{message:Function}`, but `Function` itself) using `module.exports=function ..`

log.js: (same as the question above)

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    function message(s) {
        console.log(s);
    }
    exports.message = message;
});
```

log.d.ts:(same)

```
declare module 'log'{
    export function message(s:string);
}
```

log2.js:

```
define(["require", "exports","module"],function(require, exports,module) {
    function message(s) {
        console.log(s);
    }
    module.exports = message;
});
```

log2.d.ts:

```
declare module 'log2'{
    export default function (s:string);
}
```

main.ts:

```
import log = require('log'); 
log.message("hello");  // It works

import log2 = require('log2'); 

log2("hello");  // Error error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import("log2")' has no compatible call signatures.

log2.default("hello"); // Compile passed. But runtime error on the browser (Uncaught TypeError: log2.default is not a function)
```

I compiled these *.ts files with `tsc -m amd`(tsc Version 3.2.4), and used require.js 2.3.5 to run the program on the browser. But log2 does not run( See main.ts ).

Maybe I am misunderstanding the use of `export default` in log2.d.ts . How can I write the type definition correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// log2.d.ts
declare module 'log2'{
    function message(s: string);
    export = message;
}
```

See also: [the Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require).